# Solving the recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n−\lceil\sqrt{n}\:\rceil)+\Theta(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have an algorithm that at each step can discard $\lceil\sqrt{n}\:\rceil$ possibilities at a cost from $O(n)$. The solution to the recurrence relation below is related to the question of complexity of such algorithm:

$$T(n)=T(n−\lceil\sqrt{n}\:\rceil)+\Theta(n)$$

how should i solve?

Comment: A very rough heuristics. If $T(n)\equiv C\cdot n^a$  then $C\cdot n^a\equiv (n-n^{1/2})^a+n\equiv n^a-an^{a-1}n^{1/2}+\Theta(n)$.
If $n^{a-1}n^{1/2}=\Theta(n)$ then $a=3/2$.